# installing psycopg2 using pip3 on ubuntu server gives error

Tags: server, python3, 19.04, postgresql, odoo

I am trying to setup odoo on my ubuntu server. I tried to install the dependencies using **pip3 install -r requirements.txt** where requirements.txt has the package-name of all dependencies. The installation process stops with the following error

```
Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-NN for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9oeydzud/psycopg2/
```

Which package given in the error should i install to resolve the error. Confused because installed libpq-dev on local computer.

Comment: 1. Try installing libpq from the latest pg repository (for example: "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" in apt sources for ubuntu 18.02).
2. If not working, try to install the "full" postgresql (including server) (I know, that's not a good option, but just to try)
=> What are the results?

Comment: @MichaelHooreman So it's not postgresql-server-dev-NN. Ok . I was confused because this was the server!

Comment: @r.py Well, on my system, I have installed postgresql-11 and postgresql-11-client, from the repositories I've shown you, and pip install psycopg2 worked like a charm.
Maybe please also consider using pg11 (I forgot to tell previously).